# Livewire throwing error when using paginated data

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

So I am being given this error when trying to paginate my data and send it in to a view through a livewire component.

I am trying to get all posts and display at max 5 posts per page using pagination in laravel.

Livewire version: 2.3.1
Laravel version: 8.13.0

**Error:**

```
Livewire\Exceptions\PublicPropertyTypeNotAllowedException
Livewire component's [user-posts] public property [posts] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null,
or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't
need to access them.
```

**My Component:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class UserPosts extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $posts;
    public $type;
    protected $listeners = ['refreshPosts'];



    public function delete($postId)
    {
        $post = Post::find($postId);
        $post->delete();
        $this->posts = $this->posts->except($postId);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        if($this->type == 'all')
            $this->posts = Post::latest()->paginate(5);
        else if($this->type == 'user')
            $this->posts = Post::where('user_id',Auth::id())->latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('livewire.user-posts', ['posts' => $this->posts]);
    }
}
```

**My Blade:**

```
<div wire:poll.5s>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div style="margin-top: 10px">
            <div class="post">
                <div class="flex justify-between my-2">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
                        <p class="mx-3 py-1 text-xs text-gray-500 font-semibold"
                           style="margin: 17px 0 16px 40px">{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
                    </div>
                    @if(Auth::id() == $post->user_id)
                        <i class="fas fa-times text-red-200 hover:text-red-600 cursor-pointer"
                           wire:click="delete({{$post->id}})"></i>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <img src="{{ asset('image/banner.jpg') }}" style="height:200px;"/>
                <p class="text-gray-800">{{ $post->text }}</p>
                @livewire('user-comments', [
                    'post_id' => $post->id,
                    'type' => 'all'
                    ],
                    key($post->id)
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
        {{ $posts->links() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### $posts should not be declared as a property in the Livewire component class, you passed the posts with the laravel view() helpers as data.

Remove the line

```
public $posts;
```

And replace $this->posts by $posts in the render function:

```
    public function render()
    {
        if($this->type == 'all')
            $posts = Post::latest()->paginate(5);
        else if($this->type == 'user')
            $posts = Post::where('user_id',Auth::id())->latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('livewire.user-posts', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me also. but i dont understand why this work. why public property cause this problem?

Comment: How to pass data with inline component?

Comment: just because of this one thing, gotta change the entire component.

Answer (score 2):

For my reference and who come across this issue.

Some times you need to add your `query` with the `pagination` in the `mount` or maybe in some `function` with an `id`.

Here is the two options you have to do so.

1. In the mount

As the error says

Livewire component's public property must be of type: [numeric, .... **Only protected or private** properties can be set

So in this case you can define the property as `protected` instead of `public` and call it in the render.

Quick example.

```
protected $posts;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->posts = Post::paginate(15);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.view',[
            'posts'=>$this->posts
        ]);
    }
```

2. In some function.

More elegant why is to use the `computed properties`

Quick example.

```
use WithPagination;

    public $postId;


    public function getPostsProperty(): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        return Post::find($this->postId)->comments()->paginate(10);
    }

    public function render(): Factory|View|Application
    {
        return view('livewire.view');
    }
```

Now in this example `$this->posts` can be accessed from either the component's class or Blade view. Read more from [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#computed-properties)

And more reference from `GitHub` issue [here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/825)

Comment: This should be the correct answer - it's the best way to do it, and allows you to much more cleanly hook into the various properties that may be present.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for this problem. Basically, I do not set paginate to livewire component property. Instead, I have property for filter and sort. Then before render, I run query to get data. In this  product list component, I filter by category to get product and sort it by title, price or created_at.

This is my livewire `ProductList` component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ProductCategory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Livewire\Attributes\Computed;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ProductList extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $categoryId = 1;

    public $sort = 'latest';

    public $sortColumn = 'created_at';

    public $sortOrder = 'desc';

    #[Computed]
    public function categories()
    {
        return ProductCategory::select('id', 'name')->get();
    }

    public function render(): View|Factory
    {
        return view(
            'livewire.product-list',
            [
                'products' => Product::select('id', 'title', 'price', 'thumbnail', 'slug')
                    ->where('category_id', $this->categoryId)
                    ->orderBy($this->sortColumn, $this->sortOrder)
                    ->paginate(15),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function updateSort()
    {
        switch ($this->sort) {
            case 'title_asc':
                $this->sortColumn = 'title';
                $this->sortOrder = 'asc';
                break;
            case 'title_desc':
                $this->sortColumn = 'title';
                $this->sortOrder = 'desc';
                break;
            case 'price_asc':
                $this->sortColumn = 'price';
                $this->sortOrder = 'asc';
                break;
            case 'price_desc':
                $this->sortColumn = 'price';
                $this->sortOrder = 'desc';
                break;
            default:
                $this->sortColumn = 'created_at';
                $this->sortOrder = 'desc';
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view `product-list.blade.php`:

```
@pushOnce('styles')
@vite(['resources/scss/components/product-list.scss'])
@endPushOnce

<div>
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-8 md:space-y-0 md:flex-row justify-between">
        <select name="categories" class='product-filter' wire:change="updateSort" wire:model="categoryId">
            @foreach($this->categories as $category)
            <option class="category-item" value="{{ $category->id }}" wire:key={{ $category->id }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <select name="sort" class='product-filter' wire:change="updateSort" wire:model="sort">
            @foreach(['latest' => 'latest', 'title_asc' => 'title (a->z)', 'title_desc' => 'title (z->a)', 'price_asc' => 'price: low to high', 'price_desc' => 'price: high to low'] as $sortKey=>$sortItem)
            <option class="sort-item" value="{{ $sortKey }}" wire:key={{ $sortKey }}>{{ $sortItem }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container animate__animated">
        @foreach ($products as $productIndex => $product)
        <div class="product-card" wire:key={{ $product->id }}>
            <p class="product-title">{{ $product->title }}</p>
            <p class="product-price">$ {{ $product->price }} USD</p>
            <img class="product-image" src="{{ $product->thumbnail }}" alt="Product Thumbnail" />
            <x-button content="View details" type="secondary" link="{{ 'products/' . $product->slug }}"></x-button>
        </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>

    <div class="pagination">
        {{ $products->links() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.