# public property [samples] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, livewires

I am using livewire trying to paginate the table

```
   public function mount($lab = null)
{
    $this->sample = new Sample;

    if ($lab) {
        $this->lab = Lab::find($lab);
        $this->samples = Sample::whereLabId($this->lab->id)->paginate(5);

    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
    Livewire\Exceptions\PublicPropertyTypeNotAllowedException
Livewire component's [sample-data] public property [samples] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.
```

I know that the variable $this->samples is an instant not a numeric, string or array...
but eventhow I need to do the pagination

How can I do that?

Comment: i see that you have a typo mistake there, you defined `$this->sample` but trying to assign to `$this->samples`

Comment: @Psycho I appreciate your answer but that isn't caused the issue

Comment: you need to set the variable name as $samples and not $this->samples. see here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64726050/8607640

Comment: @Psycho but if i write $samples  = Sample::whereLabId($this->lab->id)->paginate(5);     it returns nothing

Comment: that might be another case, but the error does not occur, right?

Comment: @Psycho yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Livewire can not figure out type the paginate function returns (paginate returns as instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`)
and that is not allowed at the moment .

A work around might be to remove the mount method and pass the `$sample`
with compact as shown below .

```
$samples = Sample::all();

return view('livewire.show', compact('samples'));
```